# Object with nested getters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Is it possible to achieve an object that would behave like so?

```
const constants = {
...
}

console.log(constants.foo)         -> 'foo'
console.log(constants.foo.bar)     -> 'FooBar'
console.log(constants.foo.bar.baz) -> 'foo_bar_baz'
console.log(constants.apple)       -> 'Apples'
console.log(constants.apple.pie)   -> 'Hot and tasty apple pie!'
```

So it would be basically an object which property would have its own getter. All properties would have to be independent of eachother when it comes to their values. Again, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by having each intermediate object being an object, and overriding the prototype `toString` method. Unfortunately, the SO override of `console.log` will display the whole object, rather than call the `toString` as the chrome console would - but if you look at the actual console rather than the SO console you'll see the output you expect.

You can also call `toString()` explicitly as needed.

```js
function Foo(){
  this.bar = new Bar()
}
Foo.prototype.toString = () => "foo";

function Bar(){
  this.baz = "Foo_Bar_Baz"
}
Bar.prototype.toString = () => "FooBar";

function Apple(){
  this.pie = "Hot and tasty apple pie!"
}
Apple.prototype.toString = () => "Apples";



const constants = {
  foo: new Foo(),
  apple: new Apple()
}

console.log(constants.foo)         //-> 'foo'
console.log(constants.foo.bar)     //-> 'FooBar'
console.log(constants.foo.bar.baz) //-> 'foo_bar_baz'
console.log(constants.apple)       //-> 'Apples'
console.log(constants.apple.pie)   //-> 'Hot and tasty apple pie!'
```